Anyway to simplify Terraform for_each
I have the following for_each in a data source in Terraform:
  for_each = merge([
    for virtual_network in local.virtual_networks : merge({
      for subnet in virtual_network.subnets : "${virtual_network.name}\\${subnet.name}" => {
        network_security_group = subnet.network_security_group
        resource_group_name    = virtual_network.resource_group_name
      } if try(subnet.network_security_group, null) != null
    })
  ]...)

My local.virtual_networks looks like this:
virtual_networks = [
  {
    name                = "vnet-uks-001"
    resource_group_name = "network-uks-001"
    subnets             = [
      {
        name                   = "PrivateEndpoints"
        address_prefixes       = ["10.1.0.0/24"]
        network_security_group = "nsg-uks-001"
      },
      {
        name                   = "snet-uks-001"
        address_prefixes       = ["10.1.1.0/26"]
        network_security_group = "nsg-uks-002"
      },
      {
        name             = "snet-uks-002"
        address_prefixes = ["10.1.2.0/26"]
      }
    ]
  }
]

Ideally without making a change to the local, is there a more simple for_each I can do which provides the same output.
Output:
{
  "vnet-uks-001\\PrivateEndpoints" = {
    network_security_group = "nsg-uks-001"
    resource_group_name    = "network-uks-001"
  }
  "vnet-uks-001\\snet-uks-001" = {
    network_security_group = "nsg-uks-002"
    resource_group_name    = "network-uks-001"
  }
}

This works perfectly as it is, just trying to think of any improvements to make it more user read-able.

Updated code from improvements suggested:
  for_each = merge([
    for virtual_network in local.virtual_networks : {
      for subnet in virtual_network.subnets : "${virtual_network.name}\\${subnet.name}" => {
        network_security_group = subnet.network_security_group
        resource_group_name    = virtual_network.resource_group_name
      } if can(subnet.network_security_group)
    }
  ]...)


try(subnet.network_security_group, null) != null could probably be replaced with can(subnet.network_security_group). Also are you only inputting one argument to the merge functions, or am I misreading the formatting; because that could be removed with no impact.

Your right, only the first merge is needed, the second one isnt achieving anything. And good thinking with the can function! Ill stick an update in my post with the updated code so far
